# Session RemoveAt From Gridview Button

Tags: session, indexing

I have a session and is being filled with list of items.

This is shown on a gridview basically a shopping cart with products.

Now how can I get the current index of the button removed from the gridview so that I can remove the item from the session.

I am using the Session["Cart"].RemoveAt() method but don't know what parameters I need to pass to get the current index of the item.

((List)Session["Cart"]).RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(gvCart.SelectedIndex));

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use RowCommand of gridview

```
protected void gvCart_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
       ((List)Session["Cart"]).RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
}
```